# Sorting a string based array on two conditions

Tags: c#

I have an array of strings like so

```
May#01
April#02
Jan#03
```

I need to sort this first alphabetically and then by the numeric value next to the #.
Alphabetical sort is obvious but I don't seem to get the numeric part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var input = new[] { "May#01", "April#02", "Jan#03", "Jan#02", "Jan#1" };
    var result = input.OrderBy(s => s.Split('#')[0])
        .ThenBy(s => Int32.Parse(s.Split('#')[1]));
```

Result:

```
[
"April#02",
"Jan#1",
"Jan#02",
"Jan#03",
"May#01"
]
```

The other answer will produce the output:

```
[
"April#02",
"Jan#02",
"Jan#03",
"Jan#1",
"May#01"
]
```

Which I'm assuming is incorrect as Jan#02 comes before Jan#1.

You could make my code more efficient by doing the split once and storing both parts in an anonymous class, along with the original string, but I don't want to convolute the code.

Comment: Yup that worked, thanks Ian, one last thing how do I get all months as comma separated string as a final string.

Comment: @Codehelp you can use the same `Split` method, along with `Select` and `string.Join`

Answer (score 5):

First order strings by their values (that will give you alphabetic sort). Then filter by integer value which is after # character:

```
array.OrderBy(s => s)
     .ThenBy(s => Int32.Parse(s.Split('#')[1]))
```

---

Sample:

```
string[] array = { "May#01", "April#02", "Jan#03", "April#01" };
var query = array.OrderBy(s => s)
                 .ThenBy(s => Int32.Parse(s.Split('#')[1]));
```

Result:

```
"April#01"
"April#02"
"Jan#03"
"May#01"
```